# Cant execute binary in /lib/arm64

Tags: android, process, binary

I've read that i can't execute binaries at /data/data/packagename in API 29 anymore. So i followed the Android docs and used /data/app/packagename/lib/arm64 to execute it from there but it still doesn't work is there any solution for this?

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find a solution?